# Docker API 1.26 does NOT support running a container in background mode? with http curl CLI

Tags: docker

all, is here anybody knows how could we "run a docker container in background mode with curl API invoke"? the API version is based on 1.26.

As i've simply followed the procedure of "https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/examples/#run-a-container-in-the-background" , but failed to start the container; image is based on "centos:latest".

the docker and api version is:

```
 Client:
 Version:        1.13.1
 API version:     1.26
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-208.git7d71120.el7_9.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.3
 Git commit:      7d71120/1.13.1
 Built:           Mon Jun  7 15:36:09 2021
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-208.git7d71120.el7_9.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.3
 Git commit:      7d71120/1.13.1
 Built:           Mon Jun  7 15:36:09 2021
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
 Experimental:    false
```

the http curl command execute procedure is as below:

```
# curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/v1.26/containers/create -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"Hostname": "test-centos","Image": "centos:latest", "Cmd": ["bash"]}' 
{"Id":"3058b2a9f233e11b97df8b86e5b9cb072aab54b8278a7b07deae6aa5e5b8bf36","Warnings":null}
# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
eb2eb0ae7992        centos:latest       "bash"              11 seconds ago      Created                                 frosty_bardeen


# curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST  http://localhost/v1.26/containers/f950bd796807c76c749056918d03a12b9d6cd9f7a692fc39c9a9661089d7a32c/start
f950bd796807        centos:latest       "bash"              31 seconds ago      Exited (0) 5 seconds ago
```

Comment: What do you mean that it "failed"? What was your expected behavior? I don't see anything abnormal here.

Comment: as the example shows, the command directly supports to start the container in background.  But in my experiment, the container started with the http-curl-command still appears "Exited" status.

Comment: It is because `bash` command exits right after you call it. What if you replace it with something like `tail -f /dev/null`?

Comment: unfortunately,  the result is the same, even i've ticked out the "data['cmd']" parameters.

Comment: Thanks, Ali,  with the attached "Cmd": ["sleep", "infinity"], the container started as i expected status of "UP"; sorry for my improper descriptions.

Comment: I'm glad you've found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Per what Ali Tou said to you, you need to describe your desired outcome with a little more depth, and the he is correct that the container will have exited because bash closed.

If you use `sleep infinity` you can achieve the same effect, as noted below:

```
# Create a new container where the running process is 'sleep' 
$ curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/v1.26/containers/create -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"Hostname": "test-centos","Image": "centos:latest", "Cmd": ["sleep", "infinity"]}'
{"Id":"98ca0ca601cbc62ca6aa4f926d66b70f4751474491bc40fcac2563ee8a9c270d","Warnings":[]}

# Start the container
$ curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST  http://localhost/v1.26/containers/98ca0ca601cbc62ca6aa4f926d66b70f4751474491bc40fcac2563ee8a9c270d/start

# Verify it is running
$ docker ps -a | grep 98ca
98ca0ca601cb   centos:latest                             "sleep infinity"         About a minute ago   Up 5 seconds                                                                                                                                                       sharp_noyce

# Verify we can exec
$ docker exec 98ca uname -a
Linux test-centos 5.8.0-63-generic #71~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 15 17:46:08 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This answer contains the Unix socket commands you might need, and uses the Docker cli to validate the rest

Comment: Thanks, with the attached "Cmd": ["sleep", "infinity"], the container started as i expected.

Comment: Happy to hear so, please feel free to select this as the answer if it solved your question